# Combining two results

Tags: postgresql, spree

I want to combine results on my postgres query, at the product properties. Currently it is giving me these results:

```
name        id   value                  sku     item_count
Item # 1    3    Item                   IT-EM1  3
Item # 1    2    006058465456           IT-EM1  3
Item # 2    3    Item                   IT-EM2  1
Item # 2    2    055045004505           IT-EM2  1
```

I would like it to return the following:

```
name       id#1   value#1    id#2    value#2         sku       item_count
Item # 1   3      Item       2       006058465456    IT-EM1    3
Item # 2   3      Item       2       055045004505    IT-EM2    1
```

The id is the product property id (2 being GTIN and 3 being Brand,) the value is the value of that particular product property. My query is below:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    l.property_id AS id,
    l.value AS value,
    v.sku,
    s.count_on_hand AS item_count,
FROM
    spree_variants v INNER JOIN
    spree_products p ON v.product_id = p.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    spree_stock_items s ON v.id = s.variant_id INNER JOIN
    spree_product_properties l ON l.product_id = p.id
WHERE
    s.count_on_hand > 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide your version of Postgres (as *always*). Table definitions would also be helpful - what you get with `\d tbl` in psql or valid DDL scripts - just the relevant columns, but with all constraints. Are there only two different values for `id` in the result or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered this myself. Maybe not the most elegant soltuion, but:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    l.property_id AS id,
    l.value AS value,
    li.property_id AS id_two,
    li.value AS value_two,
    v.sku,
    s.count_on_hand AS item_count,
FROM
    spree_variants v INNER JOIN
    spree_products p ON v.product_id = p.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    spree_stock_items s ON v.id = s.variant_id INNER JOIN
    spree_product_properties l ON l.product_id = p.id INNER JOIN
    spree_product_properties li ON li.product_id = p.id
WHERE
    s.count_on_hand > 0 AND
    l.property_id = 2 AND
    li.property_id = 3
```

Add the product properties column again as a different variable (l and li) then define in WHERE that l.property_id = 2 and li.property_id = 3